# How can I pass data to multiple stateful pages in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

So, I'm trying to pass data from one page to multiple pages, but here's the catch: I only want to actually navigate to one of them. I'm using this code snippet to navigate to the next page:

```
     Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (context) =>
                     TodayPage(lg_username: unameController.text)),).then((value) => _login(lg_username));
```

But now I need the lg_username data to be available in multiple other pages without actually navigating to them. Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

Comment: How about you save the data in an object that is independent from the pages? Then the pages can set the value of the data or get the data that they needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this follow:

create file **static_variable.dart**

```
class StaticVariable {
  static UserModel? user;
  static String? userId;
}
```

save `userId` or `user` data to **StaticVariable**

```
ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Navigator'),
        onPressed: () {
          StaticVariable.userId = 'YOUR USER ID';
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    TodayPage(lg_username: unameController.text)),);
        },
      )
```

Then, you can call `StaticVariable` in any file

```
Text(StaticVariable.userId ?? '')
```

Comment: Its actually works! I don't know why I never thought this way. anyway thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

in ur main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow/mySecondPage.dart';
import 'myStaticVar.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'first window',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'first window'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  void onPop(){
    print("my new set var ${StaticVariable.userId}");
    setState(() {
     
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'ur static var now ',
            ),
            Text(
                StaticVariable.userId.toString()
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          StaticVariable.userId = 'YOUR USER ID';
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    mySecondPage()),).then((value) => onPop());
        },
        tooltip: 'Go To Other Page',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

creat class with myStaticVar.dart name and put tihs inside

```
class StaticVariable {
  static String? userId;
}
```

and ur second page with name of mySecondPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'myStaticVar.dart';
class mySecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const mySecondPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<mySecondPage> createState() => _mySecondPageState();
}

class _mySecondPageState extends State<mySecondPage> {
  TextEditingController myVariblaeContorler = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(leading: IconButton(onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context);}, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),),
      body: Center(
          child: TextField(
            onSubmitted: (value){
              StaticVariable.userId = myVariblaeContorler.text;
            },
        controller: myVariblaeContorler,
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

now test it , and if u whant u can use SharedPreferences to hold the var even if u turn off ur app and start it again